# Import SQL dump into numpy matrix with datetime fields

Tags: python, mysql, csv, datetime, numpy

I need to import in a python script the data of a large SQL table (4M rows) in a format that allows me to consider every columns with a proper time (e.g. datetime)

So, first a need to dump the table to my laptop with a proper format which keeps the datatype. I tried with .csv and to import it into a list of lists but all fields are just strings and operations on datetimes are very difficult...

Second, I need a numpy-like matrix type which preserves datatypes and is efficient enough to iterate over all rows multiple times.

Can anybody help me? I'm desperate!!

Comment: So, the date(-time) column(s) values are enclosed with quotes?  
You can operate on sliced strings, can you? What have you tried?

Comment: See also:  
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html